# Setting up Vimspeak on Mac

Tags: macos, vim

I am would like to setup VimSpeak https://github.com/AshleyF/VimSpeak for my Mac. This will allow for coding in Vim using your voice, the demo video looks great, but there is little mention of how to set it up.

How do I set up VimSpeak for Mac?

Running Vim out of the terminal with OSX Mountain Lion. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VimSpeak has a native OS X port by @pselle: https://pselle.github.io/macvimspeak/

No Mono needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been wanting to get a voice programming setup for a long time. This does what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The README is quite clear: that thing is a F# sharp project that's meant to be built in Visual Studio and work on recent Windows versions. The chances of it working on Mac OS X are quite slim.

You *may* try to build it with MonoDevelop, though.

For what it's worth, I downloaded the project and opened it in a fresh install of Xamarin Studio (ex MonoDevelop) with the latest mono MDK release (3.4.0). The IDE complains right away about missing assemblies, `System.Speech` for example, and — not surprisingly — refuses to build the project.

From [that page](http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Speech) it looks like work is done to introduce `System.Speech` to a future Mono release but that's how far I will go to find an answer.

I suggest you try the mono forums, mailing lists and IRC channels.